# How to show certain elements in <td> if info is empty

Tags: html, angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I am new in angular and I am using ngFor inside a  to populate a table. My question is, if the array that is present[let i of user.acessTypes] in ngFor is empty how can I show an "Is Empty" string information in the correspondent row?

This is my table html

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
          <tr>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Acess Type</th>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let user of listUser">
            <td>{{user.email}}</td>
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-primary"
               *ngFor="let i of user.acessTypes">
               //if i is empty show "Is Empty"
               {{i.accessTypeName}}({{i.subAcessTypeName}})                  
             </button> </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

This is my JSON response

```
{
    "data": [  
        {
            "id": 1,
            "email": "jose@hotmail.com",
            "password": "$2a$10$44ghfG4Ym4COxXbj9pDBuOLBXCPRRDiIM7y77G.XEh7avm2GOxlUC",
            "isAdmin": 0,
            "acessTypes": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "accessTypeName": "User",
                    "subAcessTypeName": "Ver&Escrever"
                }
            ],
            "tomas": [],
            "consultas": [],
            "profile": "NORMALUSER"
        }
    ],
    "dataArray": null,
    "errors": []
}
```

Comment: how can i be a string or empty?

Comment: Something, the main purpose is to show an icon, but for now empty is enough

Comment: what do you mean by empty here? seems i is an object

Comment: if i does not contain any value inside, then I would like to print something like "No info inside" in the correspondent row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several approaches. One of them is working with an if-else statement the Angular way. Both `ng-container` and `ng-template` won't be part of the DOM tree after they are rendered.

Here is a nice resource that explains it in more detail: https://toddmotto.com/angular-ngif-else-then

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Acess Type</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let user of listUser">
    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
    <td>
        <ng-container *ngIf="user.acessTypes.length > 0; else noAccessTypes">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" *ngFor="let i of user.acessTypes">
                {{i.accessTypeName}}({{i.subAcessTypeName}})                  
            </button> 
        </ng-container>
        <ng-template #noAccessTypes>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Is empty</button>
        </ng-template>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thats it :) Many thanks Ruben. You must be portuguese so Obrigado :D

Answer (score 1):

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Acess Type</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of listUser">
        <td>{{user.email}}</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-primary"
                    *ngFor="let i of user.accessTypes">
                //if i is empty show "Is Empty"
                {{i.accessTypeName}}({{i.subAcessTypeName}})
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" *ngIf="user.accessTypes.length == 0">Is Empty</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @jose can you console log ``listUser``?

Comment: Console log as elements inside because it prints the table with the information in the rows that have that information. I only need to have a logic in case nothing is inside the i for certain rows

Comment: Note that I change **acessTypes** to **accessTypes** as I thought it was a typo

Answer (score 1):

You can just check using *ngIf as follows,

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" *ngFor="let i of user.acessTypes">
   <ng-template *ngIf="i">
   {{i.accessTypeName}}({{i.subAcessTypeName}})                  
   </ng-template>
   <ng-template *ngIf="!i">
     Is Empty         
   </ng-template>
</button> </td>
```

Comment: can you post what you have in user.accessTypes JSON

Comment: Done, you can check

Comment: the JSON you posted have access types. so you will not see empty message at alk and it should be accessTypes

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can create a proper validation check as follows.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
   <tr>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Acess Type</th>
   </tr>
   <tr *ngFor="let user of listUser">
      <td>{{user.email}}</td>
      <td>
         <button class="btn btn-primary"
            *ngFor="let i of user.acessTypes">
            <div *ngIf="i.accessTypeName.length == 0">
                Is Empty 
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="i.accessTypeName.length != 0">
               {{i.accessTypeName}}({{i.subAcessTypeName}})
            </div>
         </button>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```